# Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": EOF

Tags: docker, docker-registry

Encountering a very frustrating issue:
`docker pull node:21`
results in the error:

```
Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": EOF
```

When I check dockerstatus.com I see: Docker Hub Registry : Operational

I've tried installing Rancher Desktop as an alternative, but get similar errors. When I try running:
`nerdctl pull node:21`
I get a response:

```
FATA[0006] failed to resolve reference "docker.io/library/node:21": failed to do request: Head "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/node/manifests/21": EOF
```

I've tried using NordVPN to establish connections from different parts of the world. All with the same result. If I `tracert registry-1.docker.io` I get:

```
$ tracert registry-1.docker.io

Tracing route to registry-1.docker.io [3.219.239.5]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1     3 ms     3 ms     3 ms  10.5.0.1 
  2     3 ms     3 ms     3 ms  31.222.254.3 
  3     5 ms     3 ms     3 ms  ae7-678.cr0-slc1.ip4.gtt.net [66.171.225.89] 
  4    32 ms    32 ms    46 ms  ae11.cr7-dal3.ip4.gtt.net [213.200.115.26] 
  5    66 ms    33 ms    34 ms  ip4.gtt.net [209.120.154.162] 
  6    32 ms    32 ms    32 ms  150.222.206.223 
  7    32 ms    31 ms    31 ms  15.230.48.10 
  8     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  9     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 10     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 11     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 12     *        *        *     Request timed out.
```

Seems the problem is DEFINATELY with host `registry-1.docker.io` When I set my `~/.docker/daemon.json` with :

```
{
  "dns": ["8.8.8.8", "8.8.4.4"]
}
```

I get the same result. If I use `https://www.nslookup.io/domains/registry-1.docker.io/dns-records/#google` I see that Google DNS resolves IPv4 to : 54.236.113.205 - which is just baffling. I've set my machine DNS to the 8.8.8.8 and still get 3.219.239.5 in the `tracert`

Comment: That would be a networking error of some kind. What does `curl -i https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/` show? The IP you received resolved to AWS, which isn't surprising (they have a lot of IPs for this service, and they don't respond to ICMP requests (used by traceroute and ping).

Comment: `curl -i https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/`:
curl: (52) Empty reply from server

Comment: That verifies this is your network on your host and not an issue with docker's access to the network.

Answer (score 0):

I can't believe it. I forgot when I ran into a similar issue a few weeks ago that I used nslookup.io to find which IP registry-1.docker.io resolved to on a different DNS and manually added a host entry on my computer. What's even worse, I did the same thing on my laptop - forgot both! D'oh!